# Format Cells in column, if match formula, and adjacent cell is blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, vba

Is it possible for me to conditionally format cells, if they match a formula and their adjacent rows are blank?

MY sheet is as follows;
Column B holds cells in date formats, and Column P also contains date formats.

I am conditionally formatting cells in column B, providing they match the following formula;

`=NOW()-30`   (Fill the cells if they are 30 days or older)

This works fine, however, i would like to input another condition alongside it, so the formatting only applies when the cell in column P, on the same row, is blank.

So i was hoping it would look something like this, but it doesn't seem to work;

```
=AND((ISBLANK($P)),((NOW()-30)))
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you adding these formulas using VBA or typing directly into the cell?

Comment: `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($P)),((NOW()-30)))` - using `$P` is not valid. You can look at `OFFSET` function or consider R1C1 style references.

Comment: I am doing it via the conditional formatting button in the ribbon, thanks.

Comment: Hi Robin, I have changed the $P, to P4 and it doesn't seem to work either, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a formula for conditional formatting the cell is formatted if the formula results `true`.

The issue here is that `=NOW()-30` results in something like `2017-06-21 13:31`
 which is **always** `true` if casted into boolean.

So if you want to format a cell only if its date is older than 30 days then you need to check against that cell. Eg. for cell B1 use: `=(B1<=NOW()-30)`.

Or accordingly something like `=AND(ISBLANK($P1), ($B1<=NOW()-30))` for cell B1 and then copy the format into the other cells.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise making a VBA macro (much simpler and clearer in my opinion). Just make a for loop, and loop through the entire column using `cell.value` to compare values or `cell.formula` to get the formula. 
This way you can also speed things up by copying your values in a `variant`table so that you can carry out all the operations with minimal time loss (great for handling large databases).
As for the conditional formating with double conditions it would give something like this:

```
if(range(cells(2,1), cells(2,bottomrow)).formula = "formulahere" AND  range(cells(16,1), cells(16,bottomrow)).value = "") Then
'--your actions--
end if
```

Comment: Hi Diveye, will this code run each time the file is opened? As I am attempting to also eliminate a user running a macro. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: Hello Uhujkill, yes of course this can launch itself every time. All you need to do is go into your Microsoft Excel Objects within your VBA project file, look for the "ThisWorkbook" component and create a sub "Private Sub Workbook_Open()". This Sub will run every time the workbook is opened (therefore anytime someone opens your excel file) and will run the commands your inserted within the sub. This way you can easily configure all the actions you wish and have them run on launch.

Check out this tutorial for more information on how to use VBA for Excel: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work, by applying the following formula, to column B, in the conditional formatting window;

```
=($B1<=NOW()-365)*($P1="")
```

This formula only formats the cells after confirming the dates, in cells B1... are greater than 365 days, and the adjacent cells in Column P are blank. 
Thus meeting my required parameters.